# Powershell script for Searching & uninstalling 7-Zip from all fixed drives

Tags: powershell, fixed, uninstallation, 7zip, drive

I am trying to uninstall software 7-Zip from all windows machines but if I am going with standard process using its uninstallstring its doing the job but most of people have installed it on different drives & copied folder multiple location which doesn't allow standard process to remove it & now there are multiple vulnerabilities related to these.

Hence looking for some prowershell script which can search all fixed drive for folder 7-Zip & run command something like %discovered path%\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe

Would really appreciate if you can help on this, please.

Comment: Too bad `uninstall-package` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the upside down route to happiness.

Instead, find where it is installed, and run the uninstall string:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" 
-Recurse  |  Where {$_.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "*7*zip*"   }
 | ForEach-Object {
 $_.GetValue("DisplayName"); $_.GetValue("UninstallString") ;
 ; Start-Process $uninstall;
}
```

It's still an arms race for nuking new installs, but at least it's dynamic for each machine.

Comment: Will need to change the `Start-Process` section to `Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c',  $_.GetValue("UninstallString") -NoNewWindow` for it to work. Edit was rejected. Using the PowerShell `Start-Process MsiExec.exe /I{xxxx}` provides errors regarding file not found.

Comment: That assumes it's an MSI installed... If it were the UninstallString should have that in it.
The script works as is for me, I'd check your copy / paste job?

Comment: I am using same method in my tool to find registry values & removing it but the problem is if user kept the folder of 7-zip anywhere on the system (specifically server) under any folder, in such they will not be updated in registry.

hence looking some method where powershell can search each drive & remove the folder or run uninstaller from its folder.

Comment: If it isn't in the registry, it isn't installed. Does 7 zip have an run anywhere executable?

Comment: Then yes, @Vijaykhurava it isn't installed and your only choices are bad... Searching all drives recursively for the folder files, which can then be just renamed and still run. Really, I don't think this approach is right for anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply invoke the `CimMethod` of Uninstall once you locate the product using `Get-CimInstance`.

Run the below to find and remove any version of 7-zip. Not the fastest but run it and forget.

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object Name -Like '7-zip*' | `
Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Uninstall
```

Comment: Note, WMI sucks for speed. This is many, many, many times slower than searching the registry

Comment: This also will not work if the app was not installed using an MSI package.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Microsoft's Winget.

- https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli
- WinGet seems to be the ultimate tool to manage windows applications from various sources.  Winget can install apps, and uninstall apps that may have been installed from various ways\sources, such as 7zip.

For example, this works on my PC:

- Install using winget:

winget.exe install --exact --id 7zip.7zip

- Uninstall using winget, "7-Zip" will search and find "7zip.7zip", then uninstall it.

winget.exe uninstall --id 7-Zip --silent --accept-source-agreements

- Uninstall using winget, specifying the exact name "7zip.7zip".

winget.exe uninstall --exact --id 7zip.7zip --silent --accept-source-agreements

Notes:

- 7zip could have been manually installed, but winget will still uninstall it
- The --accept-package-agreements parameter might also be needed for other uses for silent use.
- To search for 7-Zip:

winget.exe search 7zip

```
Name                                            Id                     Version            Match         Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9 ZIP - open rar, zip, 7zip, gzip               9NBLGGH3TDHG           Unknown                          msstore
Easy Unrar - ZArchiver, Unzip & Zip, gzip, 7zip 9PLNC0QX58D9           Unknown                          msstore
7-Zip                                           7zip.7zip              22.00              Moniker: 7zip winget
7-Zip ZS                                        mcmilk.7zip-zstd       21.03 ZS v1.5.0 R2 Tag: 7zip     winget
NanaZip Preview                                 M2Team.NanaZip.Preview 1.2.253.0          Tag: 7zip     winget
NanaZip                                         M2Team.NanaZip         1.2.252.0          Tag: 7zip     winget
7-Zip Alpha (msi)                               7zip.7zip.Alpha.msi    21.03.00.0                       winget
7-Zip Alpha (exe)                               7zip.7zip.Alpha.exe    21.04 beta                       winget
```

- To upgrade 7-Zip:

winget.exe upgrade 7zip.7zip